# VBA to Copy data from one workbook to another workbook/worksheet not working

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm having a lot of trouble with some code in an Excel template.  The template code was not done by me but I'm using it to automate a report for my team.

let me preface my issue with how I'm getting the data to the Template:  The first steps that happen is Access runs a couple of queries and transfers the data to sheets in the Excel template and the opens the template.  Opening the triggers the macro to runs some formatting, calculations and Vlookups.  All works well until I get to the part where I copy data from one Workbook to the worksheet in another workbook.  I've researched here to see if I could find an answer but I'm pretty lost (I'm new to vba coding).

Here is the code (the Negative trend WB is opened before I get here)

```
'Copy top ten Data to paste into Negative Trend 2017
    Worksheets("Qry_Total").Range("A2:L11").Copy
'PasteSpecial Values Only
  'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Workbooks("Negative Trend 2017.xls").Activate
    Worksheets("Top Ten").Activate


'Finds the last non-blank cell (in Negative Trend column B)and paste top ten data
    Dim LastRow As String

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("B" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial

'Deselect coppied cells
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Workbooks("Negative Report Macro Template").Activate
'Disable marching ants around copied range
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Rename Tabs
    Sheets("Qry_Summary").Name = "Summary"
    Sheets("Qry_Total").Name = "Detail"
```

The code breaks here `Worksheets("Top Ten").Activate` with a

> Run_time Error '9'.

the copied data from this line `Worksheets("Qry_Total").Range("A2:L11").Copy` is not getting pasted here `Range("B" & LastRow).Select`

I"m missing something.

Just FYI, if I manually do everything from transferring the access data to the excel WB and manually triggering the "run report" macro everything works just fine.    I'm lost.

Comment: The `ActiveWorkbook` (implicitly referenced) apparently does not have a `"Top Ten"` worksheet. Qualify the `Worksheets` member call with an explicit `Workbook` object instance (solid), or make sure the correct/intended workbook is active (frail).

Comment: I strongly recommend reworking this piece of code to stop using `.Select` and `.PasteSpecial`. Instead, directly provide the destination range when using `.Copy`. If you do that, you can get rid of all the `.Activate` calls as well.

Comment: "and manually triggering the "run report" macro everything works just fine" - that's only because the correct workbook happens to be active when you do that. Avoid `.Select` and `.Activate`.

Comment: How do I rework this to get rid of the .Select and .PasteSpecial as you describe?    I"m not sure I understand this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried condensing it down for you. To avoid special paste you just assign the values of one range to the other. To avoid select you just apply whatever you would use on a selection on a fully defined range. Since you know your bounds it's easy enough to figure out what the necessary range on the new sheet would be to house all of the values.

If you feel like writing out the workbook and sheet every time is a bit of a hassle you could try using with blocks, or you could create a new variable that's either a worksheet or workbook and set it to be the object you want. An example of this would be

```
Dim TopTen As Worksheet
Dim NegTrend As Workbook

Set TopTen = Workbooks("Negative Trend 2017.xls").Worksheets("Top Ten")
Set NegTrend = Workbooks("Negative Trend 2017.xls")

LastRow = TopTen.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

The variable is now the worksheet and you can call the same properties you would normally call with a sheet like `Range, Cells` etc but with less typing and still keeping it fully defined.

Here's your code, condensed down and implementing the with blocks that I had mentioned above.

```
Sub test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With Workbooks("Negative Trend 2017.xls").Worksheets("Top Ten")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("B" & LastRow & ":M" & LastRow + 9).Value = _
        Workbooks("Negative Report Macro Template").Worksheets("Qry_Total").Range("A2:L11").Value
    End With

    With Workbooks("Negative Report Macro Template")
        .Sheets("Qry_Summary").Name = "Summary"
        .Sheets("Qry_Total").Name = "Detail"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The Condensed down code worked perfectly. Thanks for the information.  I'll hang on to this as I'm sure I will need to use it as a foundation for other reports I'm converting to automated processes.  Thanks for your talents and everyone's input.